# Minecraft Ender IO destroying magical crops

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I saw some YouTubers using an Ender IO farming station to automate Magical Crops. So I thought, "Hey, I'll try and use that to get my resources more efficiently". So I grinded, exhausted most of my resources, and got my farming station.

As soon as I gave it what it needed, instead of it harvesting the crops like it would've if I had used my fist, it harvested the essence and the crop was gone. I was lucky enough to have some backup seeds so I wasn't entirely ruined, but I want to know how to fix this so I can get back on my feet, and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Magical Crop's mod options, and set the option for crops to replant themselves when harvested to true. The Farming Station should work normally after that change.

Comment: I can't config magical crops